# How to push the original line down after copy and paste in Vim?

Tags: vim

I just started with Vim recently and I got stuck with a basic problem!

When I want to copy and paste more than one line of my codes and paste it in the other place, the original codes will not move down after I paste my lines on top of them. For example, my original codes is look like:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

after I using visual mode to select all of them and using 'y' to copy, then I move my cursor to the top-left of my file and use "P" to paste them on the top of my file, it becomes:

```
aaa aaa
bbb bbb
ccc ccc
```

instead of what I want

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I don't know what I just got wrong? or is this the way how vim deal with copy and paste? so I need to push the original lines down first before I paste them on it? it's sounds a little inconvenient to do so!

Can anyone tell me how to do what I want easily? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are using Visual-Block mode (Ctrl-v), try selecting the lines with Visual-Line mode instead (Shift-v)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the register contents you've yanked originate from a *blockwise* selection. Then, on paste, Vim will indeed insert the contents inline, making space for the amount of text in the register, instead of inserting brand new lines.

You should use the `V` command for *linewise* visual selection. Then, the correct expected paste behavior will happen on paste automatically.

Note that my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) offers paste mappings that force a certain mode. So, with its `glp` mapping, you could force linewise pasting from a blockwise selection. But it's better to do the "right" selection in the first place.

Comment: What is the difference between `Shift-v` and just `v`? Both appear to behave the same way, except `v` highlights each line as you move through the file.

Comment: @sherrellbc `v` allows to select incomplete lines, e.g. single words `Shift-v` always selects complete lines.